# Inno Setup: add fields to InputQueryPage depending on components selected

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I have an input query page, which asks the user for ports depending on what components are selected.

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  { Create the page }
  ConfigPage :=
    CreateInputQueryPage(
      wpSelectComponents, 'User input', 'User input',
      'Please specify the following information, then click Next.');
  { Add items (False means it's not a password edit) }
  if IsComponentSelected('broker') then
  begin
    ConfigPage.Add('MQTT Broker port:', False);
    { Set initial values (optional) }
    ConfigPage.Values[0] := ExpandConstant('1883');
   end;
end;
```

The issue I am finding here is that `InitializeWizard` is always called prior to component selection, so `IsComponentSelected('broker')` is always called.

Is there any way around this? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy. For a really generic solution, you would have to create the custom page only when leaving the components selection page (e.g. in [`NextButtonClick`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=NextButtonClick) with `CurPageID` equal `wpSelectComponents`). That's doable, but Inno Setup allows user to go back to the components page. When the user does that, you would have to remove the custom page, re-creating it later. But you would lose the data the user might have entered on the custom page. So you would have to persist the data somehow. All that is doable, but lot of work.

---

If it is about few input boxes only, consider instead disabling the boxes that are not relevant for the current components selection:

```pascal
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = ConfigPage.ID then
  begin
    ConfigPage.Edits[0].Enabled := IsComponentSelected('foo');
    ConfigPage.PromptLabels[0].Enabled := ConfigPage.Edits[0].Enabled;

    ConfigPage.Edits[1].Enabled := IsComponentSelected('bar');
    ConfigPage.PromptLabels[1].Enabled := ConfigPage.Edits[1].Enabled;
  end;
end;
```

A step further would be to hide the boxes instead of disabling them (use `Visible` instead of `Enabled`). But then you would have to rearrange the boxes. But that's still easier then re-building the page.